# Extracting a specific keyword from a string

Tags: php, string

Currently I have a string value that is coming in which looks something like this: `I'm interested in the property LP11503`. Now here the term I want to extract is `LP11503`. Basically the term should have LP in the beginning followed by numbers from 0-9.

I've tried using `preg_match_all` to get the numbers from my string, but this method extracts all the numbers in the string. So basically if the string were to be `I'm interested in 2 bedroom property LP11503`, it would print out both 2 and 11503. I want it to print `LP11503`.
Here is what I've tried so far which is printing all my numbers in the string:

```
$data = array(
    'name' => "jay",
    'number'=> '1234',
    'message'=> 'I\'m interested in the property LP11503'
);
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $data['message'], $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Now how do I only extract the keyword `LP[0-9]`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why not change your regular expression accordingly?

Comment: http://regular-expressions.info — If you want to match "LP followed by numbers" then you should write an appropriate expression…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the pattern `\b[A-Z]+[0-9]+\b`:

```php
$message = "I'm interested in 2 bedroom property LP11503";
preg_match_all("/\b[A-Z]+[0-9]+\b/", $message, $matches);
print_r($matches[0][0]);  // LP11503
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all('/LP\d+/', $data['message'], $matches);
print_r($matches[0][0]);
```